# Cloudflare / Chrome DNS Cache and TTL

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname, a-records

We have a website that we recently revamped.

The domain it lived on use to have a CNAME record for @ and www pointing to a different domain while the site was being developed.

We have now deployed the site (48+ hours ago) and chrome users who have previously visited the site are still being redirected to the domain the old CNAME pointed to.

The new DNS configuration is an @ record pointing to the server and the a CNAME for www that also points to the same server (but a proxy).

We cannot figure out how to get existing users on chrome to pick up these DNS changes, if a user is to clear their browser cache, the site will work just fine. That said we cannot tell thousands of users to clear their cache.

Does anyone know how we can get users to pick up the new records?
The original TTL on the site was set to AUTO on cloudflare through the cloudflare proxy. I'm told this makes the TTL around 5 mins however its been over 48 hours and users are still having this issue. We have also purge the cache on cloudflare multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the TTL on each record, you just have to wait it out